# Why is memory (rss) from ps command different than memory seen in top command?

Tags: memory, macos, ps, top

Here on MacOS Catalina, when checking the memory usage of a process I see that the `ps` command shows a RSS value which is different from the memory usage shown in top:

```
$> ps e -o command,vsize,rss,%mem|grep "myapplication"|head -n 1
myapplication  4594896  51364  0.3
```

**RSS -> 51364**

```
top
PID    COMMAND       %CPU TIME    #TH             #WQ  #PORT MEM    
48106  myapplication 115.7        09:06.12 69/1   1    101   37M+
```

**MEM -> 37M**

Why this difference?

**UPDATE:**

Another example with IntelliJ process:

```
top -pid 357
```

```
PID  COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #POR MEM    PURG CMPRS  PGRP PPID STATE    BOOSTS        %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID       FAULTS    COW   MSGSENT  MSGRECV  SYSBSD
357  idea         2.6  03:16:46 112   1    925  4906M  0B   1583M  357  1    sleeping  0[2884]      0.00000 0.00000    281451937 28337096  54627 8404446+ 2733245+ 156093159+
```

Top shows **4906M**

```
ps aux
```

```
USER               PID  %CPU %MEM        VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND

xxxxxxx            357   3.6 14.5 180050484 2430728   ??  S     1:44PM 196:48.70 /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea -psn_0_73746
```

ps shows RSS **2430728** (KB)

Comment: Can you add column labels to the `top` output? The meaning and the order of the columns change on different `top` versions. Which version of top are you using? On which OS?

Comment: Added columns. Actually I'm using MacOs Catalina

Comment: There are many versions of top.  Which one are you using in what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is ps is showing the resident memory while top is showing total or virtual memory (e.g. including swapped out and shared).

There are a lot of questions about this, including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880784/what-is-rss-and-vsz-in-linux-memory-management but that is why they are different values here.

Comment: I'm nos sure about that. Check the UPDATE. ps shows both VSZ and RSS, and both values are different from MEM in top

Comment: Top also supports directly showing RSS and VSZ.  MEM is a different metric, so it should not be surprising it is different.